# sw.js:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://www.example.com/_nuxt/workbox.4c4f5ca6.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js

I'm getting this error

```
sw.js:1 Refused to execute script from
'https://www.example.com/_nuxt/workbox.4c4f5ca6.js' because its MIME
type ('text/plain') is not executable. (anonymous) | @ | sw.js:
```

and then

sw.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 
 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://www.example.com/_nuxt/workbox.4c4f5ca6.js' failed to load.
 at https://www.example.com/sw.js:1:1

Nuxt Universal mode / Node 10.15.1

I tried even several fresh installations with minimal config and the problem persists
This is the content of /sw.js where it fails

```
importScripts('/_nuxt/workbox.4c4f5ca6.js')
```

Comment: Nelson, is this a local file? If so have you set correct MIME type.  Check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types

Comment: After a lot of research I noticed that that happens with the nuxt universal app ONLY when deployed to gcloud AppEngine. The yaml files contains

handlers:
  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: .nuxt/dist/client
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt))$
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt)$
    secure: always

  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always

env_variables:
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
  NODE_ENV: 'production'

and adding the text/javascript mime type changes nothing